# How to export data from AWS Aurora Postgres DB to Redshift?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, psycopg2, amazon-aurora

I have a **Postgres DB** hosted on **AWS Aurora** from which I need to retrieve data and insert it into **Redshift**.

My current approach is as follows:

1. Create an **Aurora DB** connection using **Psycopg2**.
2. With **Aurora** connection created above, query the **Aurora DB** table and export the resultset as a **CSV** file to **S3** using `OUTFILE`
3. From **S3**, **Redshift** connection using **Psycopg2**.

I'm trying to optimize this by removing the **S3** service and connecting **Aurora** to **Redshift** directly.

Here's what I want to do for which I couldn't find resources:

Query the **Aurora** table - table1 and directly export the result set into the **Redshift** table - table1.

I'm not even sure if this is possible with the current system. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to get data into an Amazon Redshift database:

- `COPY` command to load from Amazon S3
- `INSERT` statement to insert data provided as part of the SQL statement

The `COPY` method is recommended for normal data loading. It runs in parallel across slices and stores the data as efficiently as possible given that it is appending data.

The `INSERT` command is acceptable for a *small number* of inserts, but not a good idea for inserting lots of rows. Where possible, insert multiple rows at a time. It is acceptable to use `INSERT ... SELECT` statements, which can insert bulk data from a different table in one operation.

So, the only way to remove Amazon S3 from your operation is to code the data into an `INSERT` statement, but this is not an optimal way to load the data.

Comment: As per my current approach, I can upload the files to `S3` and use `COPY` command to load them into Redshift. I'm just thinking if there is even better way to directly dump from Aurora DB to Redshift.

Comment: Nope. Only those two ways. Other tools can do it for you (eg AWS Database Migration Service), but they use the `COPY` command too.